# What is the difference between FFmpeg Android and FFmpeg Android Java?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg in a new app and found these two repositories on GitHub: http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android/ and http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/.

What are their differences? I mean, Android NDK is just a way to put native code together with your Java code, right? If so, using FFmpeg-android as a shared native library and using FFmpeg-android-java which seems to be a java library that encapsulates calls to the shared native library, are the same thing. Or am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: do you just need a binary or do you want to control the build?  looks as if the first will let u rebuild ffmpeg . 2nd assumes u just want to import a prebuilt binary that may or may not cover the ABI's u need?

Comment: I just need to use FFmpeg in my app without penalizing performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one includes a full android project and precompiled libraries. The first one is only a bunch of shell scripts that will download and compile different tools (including ffmpeg) using the NDK that you provide.